# I'm receiving a Surface Error in Pygame over font. How do I fix?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7

I'm using Pygame 1.9.6 and Python 3.7.4. I'm making a title screen for Space Invaders. But when I run the code for calling the function that runs the font it shows:

```
screen.blit(cover_font, (150, 250))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.font.Font
```

So I have on three other occasions have displayed text no problem in my code.

These are the three other font displays:

```
# Score
score_value = 0
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

# Game Over Text
over_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 64)

# Paused
paused_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 64)


def game_paused():
    paused_text = paused_font.render("Paused", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(paused_text, (275, 250))


def show_score(x, y):
    score = font.render("Score: " + str(score_value), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(score, (x, y))


def game_over_text():
    over_text = over_font.render("GAME OVER", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(over_text, (200, 250))
```

But for some reason it pops up the error for this code:

```
# Cover Text
cover_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 64)
def cover_text():
    cover = cover_font.render("SPACE INVADERS", True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(cover_font, (150, 250))
```

So I have no idea what the issue is at all. The code is basically the same on all levels. I'm just calling the fonts at different times during the game. So I appreciate the advice as always. Thank you.

Comment: It's just a simple syntax error: that call should have `screen.blit( cover, ...` which is the surface, whereas `cover_font` is obviously the font.  (last line in the question code).

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally tried to *blit* the *Font* object rather than the *Surface* object. While the name of the *Font* is `cover_font`,  the name of the *Surface* is `cover`:

<s>`screen.blit(cover_font, (150, 250))`</s>

```py
screen.blit(cover, (150, 250))
```